# JavaScript function works perfectly but giving error

Tags: jquery

```
function scrollBottom()  {
    var myDiv = $("#configComponent");
    myDiv.animate({
        scrollTop: $(".drpMenuDiv").position().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

It gives following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).position(...) is undefined
scrollTop: $(".drpMenuDiv").position().top
```

Comment: The code itself looks fine, although you need to animate `scrollTop` on the `body` or `html`. Can you set up a http://jsfiddle.net which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Or post your HTML, please

Comment: Can we see your HTML which contains that div?

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe: It would fail on the previous line if he/she hadn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error you're getting (from Firefox) is:

```
$(...).position(...) is null
```

(`null`, not `undefined`). (From Chrome it would be `Cannot read property 'top' of null`.)

That tells you that there are no matches for the selector `.drpMenuDiv`, so `position()` is returning `null`.

If that's possible, you want a guard in there:

```
function scrollBottom()  {
    var myDiv = $("#configComponent");
    var menuDivPos = $(".drpMenuDiv").position();
    if (menuDivPos) {
        myDiv.animate({
            scrollTop: menuDivPos.top
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Or alternately, animate to some default position if there's no `menuDiv`:

```
function scrollBottom()  {
    var myDiv = $("#configComponent");
    var menuDivPos = $(".drpMenuDiv").position();
    myDiv.animate({
        scrollTop: menuDivPos ? menuDivPos.top : 0
    }, 1000);
}
```

That example animates to `0` if there are no matches.

Comment: @user3690332: That tells you there's no match for the selector the first time, and that there *is* a match for the selector the second time (between the two, you've added at least one element with that class, or added that class to at least one existing element).

Comment: so what will be solution for that ?

Comment: @user3690332: Check whether there's a match. I've added a couple of examples.